# In the lectures by Swami Vivekananda on "Raja Yoga", Why is there no mention of 'Ajna'?

Tags: yoga, vivekananda, chakras, raja-yoga

In the following lecture snippet, the term '*Ajna*' is missing; but I am not sure, why?
Is there any specific reason, for which he did not mention it?

> To open that Suṣumnâ is the prime object of the Yogî. According to
>   him, along this Suṣumnâ are ranged these centres of distribution, or,
>   in more figurative language, these lotuses, as they are called. The
>   lowest one is at the lowest end of the spinal cord, and is called
>   Mûlâdhâra, the next one is called Svâdiṣṭhâna, the next Maṇipûra, the
>   next Anâhata, the next Viśuddha, and the last, which is in the brain,
>   is the Sahasrâra, or “the thousand petalled.” [[source]](http://www.yogebooks.com/english/vivekananda/1896rajayoga.pdf)

There are [seven principle Chakras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra#Muladhara) in the body which are:  Muladhara, Swadhisthana, Manipura, Anahata, Vishuddha, Ajna and the highest Chakra is called the Sahsrara Chakra. Swami Vivekananda in the above lecture has talked about every Chakras except the Ajna Chakra.

Comment: For those who don't have a clue about *'Ajna'* or Swami Vivekananda's lectures, you may want to give more info as, why do you feel that he should have mentioned it in his lectures.

Comment: who is the source that you cited? He has at the beginning a copyright on the publication. If anyone has the copyright (and the copyright ran out a long time ago) it is the Ramakrishna Mission. Can't comment on the quote unless you use a more reliable source to start. Try Volume 1 here - http://www.advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php

Answer (score 4):

There is mention of Ajna.

> The Yogi alone has the Sushumna open. When this Sushumna current
>   opens, and begins to rise, we get beyond the sense, our minds become
>   supersensuous, superconscious — we get beyond even the intellect,
>   where reasoning cannot reach. To open that Sushumna is the prime
>   object of the Yogi. According to him, along this Sushumna are ranged
>   these centres, or, in more figurative language, these lotuses, as they
>   are called. The lowest one is at the lower end of the spinal cord, and
>   is called Mulâdhâra, the next higher is called Svâdhishthâna, the
>   third Manipura, the fourth Anâhata, the fifth Vishuddha, the sixth
>   **Âjnâ** and the last, which is in the brain, is the Sahasrâra, or "the thousand-petalled". Of these we have to take cognition just now
>   of two centres only, the lowest, the Muladhara, and the highest, the
>   Sahasrara. All energy has to be taken up from its seat in the
>   Muladhara and brought to the Sahasrara. The Yogis claim that of all
>   the energies that are in the human body the highest is what they call
>   "Ojas". Now this Ojas is stored up in the brain, and the more Ojas is
>   in a man's head, the more powerful he is, the more intellectual, the
>   more spiritually strong. One man may speak beautiful language and
>   beautiful thoughts, but they, do not impress people; another man
>   speaks neither beautiful language nor beautiful thoughts, yet his
>   words charm. Every movement of his is powerful. That is the power of
>   Ojas.

The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 1, Raja Yoga, Chapter V